# What is the RA Media Server?

Tags: windows-vista

I am just wondering what the RA Media Server account files and folders are doing on my machine. Should they be there or is it just a default account for vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this thread](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/t/19252460.aspx), on the Dell Community forum. From the thread:

> this account is created by Dell Remote
>   Access application.
>
> uninstall Dell remote access 
>   application and delete the user RA
>   Media server

You can find more about it there, including steps for uninstalling Dell Remote Access and deleting the account. You don't normally need this account, you can safely delete it, if you want.